# python 2.7.5 why does this require an integer

Tags: python-2.7

where why does this statement require an integer

```
with open('file, 'r', 'ignore'):
```

output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PYdown.py", line 9, in <module>
    with open(links, 'r', 'ignore') as links:
TypeError: an integer is required
```

I've tried to find documentation to tell me why an integer is required but I couldn't find why open() needs an integer

Comment: Where did you get `'ignore'` from? The official docs specify an integer for `buffering` as third argument: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#open

Comment: Python *3* has an optional `errors` parameter which takes a string. In that version of Python using `errors = 'ignore'` actually makes sense. The best fix might be to move to Python 3 since Python 2 is depreciated.

Comment: @UnholySheep I'm not exactly sure but I think my research may have been python 3 while looking for examples to understand the documentation better

Comment: @JohnColeman since the machine that I'm using to do this isn't mine, that will be difficult to update to python 3

Comment: Python 2 *was* deprecated; it's full-on unsupported now.

Comment: If you have to use Python 2 then you have to use Python 2 -- but if this is for a client you could perhaps suggest to them that they upgrade to Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the documentation

open(name[, mode[, buffering]])

1st variable filename
2nd open mode
3rd buffer type

"The optional buffering argument specifies the file’s desired buffer size: 0 means unbuffered, 1 means line buffered, any other positive value means use a buffer of (approximately) that size (in bytes). A negative buffering means to use the system default, which is usually line buffered for tty devices and fully buffered for other files. If omitted, the system default is used. 2"

These are the buffer values.

Seems like you are checking python 3 documentation based on the syntax you show.

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The third argument is `buffering`, which is an integer.

You can use the `ignore` string in the `errors` argument in Python 3

You can use it then as follows:

```
with open('file, 'r', errors='ignore'):
```

Check differences in the documentation for `open` in Python 2 and 3:

- [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#open)
- [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: What you can do in Python 3 isn't relevant to the OP.